# How do you make git use CRLF in temporary files?

Tags: git, bash

In Windows 7, git would open notepad, and it worked fine, as the temporary files that git created during eg. `git commit` or `git rebase -i` contained CRLF.

I am currently using the Windows 10 preview, and have set core.editor to notepad. However, the temporary files are being created with LF instead of CRLF, which notepad does not support.

On both platforms, I am using the Git Shell that GitHub for Windows gives you, set to Bash.

How do I make git use CRLF in temporary files, like it did on my Windows 7?

Comment: Use a different editor. Notepad.exe also doesn’t support the waiting Git does when prompting for the message (afaik), so you can’t really edit your commit messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found the answer: GitHub for Windows includes a utility called gitpad which converts the file to CRLF and then calls notepad. This had been set as the EDITOR variable on my Windows 7 system, so it all worked transparently. Setting core.editor to gitpad on my Windows 10 system solved the problem.